# How can I make a Windows shortcut that launches Bash and runs commands?

Tags: windows, bash, cmd.exe, shortcuts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've created a windows shortcut with a target that looks like

`"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" php /c/script.php`

(I know I could just use my windows verison of php cli to run this, but out of curiosity)

When I click my shortcut it just pops open a cmd window and closes (where the script should take minutes to run.

Is there a way to pipe commands to bash.exe on windows?

Comment: It's simple, just wait and hello world, so i should see something. But the cmd window pops open for a moment and closes.

Comment: Many things I see that are odd about this question.  If it were WSL, then "/c/script.php" would be  "/mnt/c/script.php".. it it were CYGWIN or MINGW, then bash.exe wouldn't be in Windows/System32.  What 'Unix' are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If this is WSL, use **bash.exe -c "command to run"** as in

***C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "vi ~/.bashrc"***

or

***C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "php /mnt/c/script.php"***

Comment: Thank you! The `-c` argument worked great. It was tough to choose which one to accept as answer as they're both great.

Comment: Yes I'm aware. afaik I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, [bash.exe has been deprecated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#deprecated-wsl-commands). You should use `wsl.exe` in command lines. Use Windows Insiders Builds 17063 and above for the interoperability feature in WSL. For your case, both of this may work:

```bat
wsl.exe php /mnt/c/MyFiles/test.php
wsl.exe --exec php /mnt/c/MyFiles/test.php
```

Here is the `wsl.exe` usage information:

> Usage: wsl.exe [Argument] [Options...] [Command]
>
> Arguments to run Linux binaries:
>
> ```
> If no command line is provided, wsl.exe launches the default shell.
>
> --exec, -e <Command>
>     Execute the specified command without using the default Linux shell.
>
> --
>     Pass the remaining command line as is.
> ```

For further details, read [WSL interoperability with Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems#interoperability-between-windows-and-linux-commands).

Comment: Thank you for the heads up about bash.exe's deprecation. I'll use wsl from here on out. And your example worked perfectly, thank you!