# Seeking equivalent wsl.exe command line

Tags: windows-10, bash-scripting

The following single command line in a Windows Desktop shortcut Target field will ping an address and timestamp it.

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "ping 1.0.0.1 | while read line; do echo `date` - $line; done"
```

Example output:

```
Fri Nov 27 14:08:05 CST 2020 - PING 1.0.0.1 (1.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
Fri Nov 27 14:08:05 CST 2020 - 64 bytes from 1.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=26.7 ms
Fri Nov 27 14:08:06 CST 2020 - 64 bytes from 1.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=35.5 ms
Fri Nov 27 14:08:07 CST 2020 - 64 bytes from 1.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=42.0 ms
```

I read [here](https://superuser.com/a/1413738/428697) that wsl.exe should be used instead of bash but I cannot figure out how to create the equivalent command.

(To do any of this in Windows 10 requires that you enable "Windows Subsystem for Linux" in Windows 10 and install Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store per [this HTG article](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you linked is wrong : `bash.exe` has not been deprecated, and in your case
it is even mandatory.

The reason is that, while WSL has a
[command parameter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference#wslexe),
it only allows a single command, so it will interpret the following command line as
a single invocation that won't work:

[image]

Trying to use built-in shell commands will also not work:

[image]

In short, you are forced to use the `bash` command for your example.
If you have more than one Linux distribution installed in WSL, `bash` will invoke
the shell of the distribution that is defined as the default.

Answer (score 0):

> I read [here](https://superuser.com/a/1413738) that wsl.exe should
> be used instead of bash but I cannot figure out how to create the
> equivalent command.

Just replace `bash.exe -c` with `wsl.exe --exec bash -c` :
<sup>1</sup>

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe --exec bash -c
 "ping 1.0.0.1 | while read line; do echo `date` - $line; done"
```

This works fine in [`cmd.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd).
I recommend trying it!
<sup>2</sup>

Output example :

```
date - PING 1.0.0.1 (1.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
date - 64 bytes from 1.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=4.58 ms
date - 64 bytes from 1.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=4.31 ms
^C
```

I learned this myself just a few days ago by reading [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1632147).

You are right that [**`bash.exe` has been deprecated**
(as have `wslconfig.exe` and `lxrun.exe`)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#deprecated-wsl-commands).

#### References

- [How to run a Linux command in WSL from Windows](https://superuser.com/a/1413738)
- [The command interpreter in Windows, `cmd.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)
- [How to send commands from Windows to WSL](https://superuser.com/a/1632147)

---

<sup>1</sup>
In `wsl.exe --exec bash -c`, the `bash` is the **Linux**
command and **not the Windows** `bash.exe` command.
This is (indirectly) clear if you try replacing `bash` with `bash.exe`
– and experience that then there is no output.

<sup>2</sup>
To open the command line (as administrator) –
hit <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd`, hold down
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
(Then copy-paste the command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.)