# How can I automate sending commands from Windows to Linux (WSL/Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, automation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to automate compiling my program for Linux through WSL running Ubuntu 20 so that I can set up an IDE task windows-side that will do the compilation for me on Linux.
I thought of making a win32 app to launch Ubuntu executable and send commands to its stdin as if I was entering them manually, but since Ubuntu is UWP, I don't think this is possible?
The parameters to the automation script would be path to the main source file's directory, main source file name, and anywhere from 1 to 4-5  other switches.
I expect the automation to be silent.
Example of automated commands:

```
cd /mnt/<provided path>
compiler -switch1 -switch2 -switch3 -out <provided executable file name> <provided source file name>
```

The compiler would be accessible from anywhere because of environment variable set in .bashrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I upvoted [the `bash.exe` answer](https://superuser.com/a/1632044) after scanning it too quickly, before realizing that it was recommending (the outdated) `bash.exe`.  So I'm going to provide what I hope is a "better answer".

Note that `bash.exe` is listed by Microsoft as a ["historic command"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference#additional-commands), which in my opinion is just one step above "deprecated".

The currently [recommended way of launching a WSL instance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference#wslexe) is with the `wsl.exe` command (or just `wsl` when called from PowerShell, CMD, or scripts under either interpreter).  For instance (using the `bash.exe` examples of the previous question):

Given a file `/mnt/c/Temp/your_script.sh` (set as executable, of course) containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo Hello
cd /home
pwd
```

Then `wsl -e "/mnt/c/Temp/your_script.sh"` (in PowerShell) would execute that file and result in:

```
Hello
/home
```

The `-e` (also `--exec`) argument to wsl runs whatever command comes after it *as* the default shell.  So `wsl -e ls` would do a directory listing without ever invoking `bash` (or even `sh`).

The shebang-in-a-script method is one way of running the commands *within* `bash`, but you can also invoke a command (or commands) like:

```
wsl -e bash -c "echo Hello; cd /home; pwd"
```

Note, however, that:

```
echo "echo Hello; cd /home; pwd" | wsl
```

Will *not* work, at least in PowerShell, since PowerShell has the annoying "feature" of appending a carriage-return (`\r`) to any output piped to a console executable such as `wsl.exe`.

Among other features, `wsl.exe` can also:

- Launch or run a command in a different WSL instance, if you have more than one distribution or instance installed (e.g. `wsl -d kali`)
- Launch into or run a command as a different user without a password (e.g. `wsl -u root visudo`)

Comment: This basically does the same thing as the bash, and still requires modification to .bashrc for environment variables to work (which is necessary because the program I'm trying to call does not work otherwise), but good to know that wsl is the prefered way of doing it.

Comment: Agreed - Should be about the same thing as the `bash.exe` version, but with a few more features.  But I'm still confused on the `.bashrc`.  It really shouldn't get called at all when `bash -c` is run (You should have to *force* it to be interactive with `bash -ic` [like so](https://askubuntu.com/a/1209635/1165986)).  But try this:  `wsl -e bash --norc --noprofile -c "echo Hello; cd /home; pwd"`.  That explicitly disables `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Thanks for the -ic switch. That's what I needed the whole time, but didn't know it. I *need* for it to read the bashrc or otherwise it doesn't work correctly for what I need.

Comment: Excellent - I was thinking it should work without it, but good to know that making it run interactively "forcibly" works for you.

Comment: The compiler requires having its path set as an environment variable, or otherwise it doesn't see the system libraries. Btw, would you have any clue why my upvote on your answer seems not to stick? I click on up vote, it goes to 1, then resets to 0.

Comment: As far as the vote - Might be that someone downvoted it, so goes to 0.  I'll know for sure when I get 9 more rep and get the "See votes" ability ;-).

Comment: As far as .bashrc and the compiler variables, that's what I was alluding to in the first comment on the other post. If you are doing your scripting from PowerShell or CMD, then (to me at least), it makes sense that that is where you'd set the necessary environment variables.  So in PowerShell, you'd add the environment variable there, then add that variable name to the [WSLENV](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/) variable. It should then work in the launched WSL session. But as long as the `.bashrc` thing with `-ic` is working for you ...

Comment: Another option is to set your compiler options in a shell script, which you both source from `.bashrc` and you source in the script you are passing in to WSL.  It's sort of an ideological thing - `.bashrc` is really designed to be for *interactive* sessions, which this is not.

Comment: Thanks; that's a fair point.

Comment: @Henke Ah, right - I think this is due to semicolon quoting issues in CMD (which I try to stay away from, for the most part )

Comment: Just a note. The command `echo "echo Hello; cd /home; pwd" | wsl`
doesn't work in cmd.exe, but this is because of the missing
`bash -c` right after the first `echo`, and because of a missing `-e`
at the end.
The response is
`-bash: line 1: echo Hello; cd /home; pwd: No such file or directory`.
The command
`echo bash -c "echo Hello; cd /home; pwd" | wsl.exe -e` works just
fine and outputs the same as
`wsl.exe -e bash -c "echo Hello; cd /home; pwd"`.

Answer (score 1):

WSL makes it very easy to run applications from the other environment - in both directions. Within Windows you can use `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` to launch any commands using Bash within your WSL GNU/Linux.

For example - script:

```
c:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "/mnt/c/Temp/your-bash-cmd.sh"

type C:\Temp\your-bash-cmd.sh | c:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
```

Or the commands to run:

```
c:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "ls -al ; echo DONE"
```

Take note to use the right file system path appropriate for each environment, and that scripts passed from Windows to Bash would need to be encoded with Linux line breaks.

Comment: Thanks very much. That should've been obvious. There's one problem, though: it doesn't seem to respect environment variables, i.e., .bashrc. If I do cd $SRC, it does nothing.

Comment: See [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/) for information on passing Windows environment variables to WSL and vice-versa.  If you are talking about setting environment variables in `.bashrc`, note that `bash` doesn't read that file when executed with the `-c` option.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I meant that running bash.exe without any parameters, and hooking its stdout and stderr results in it acting different to how it would normally. A part of that seems to be a part of .bashrc that says: # If not running interactively, don't do anything. commenting next few lines below that seems to fix the environment variables problem, but certain things still seem weird, e.g., the cd command doesn't give any feedback.

Comment: Honestly a little confused by that situation, since `.bashrc` should *only* be executed by `bash` on interactive sessions, right?